# Reduce arrow thickness with css

Tags: css

I would like to make my arrow  tinnier. I was not able to change the font-weigth so not sure what to do. This is my code.

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="left-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
```

[image: current arrow]

Comment: The property is spelled `font-weight`. Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: There is very little weight control over UTF-8 Dingbats.  Why not just use an image?

Answer (score -1):

You should use font-awesome icon.

```
.slideshow .buttons button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight:normal;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the icon that you have and not use a font awesome icon like the above then do this:

```
.left-button {
    font-size: 20px; (adjust as needed)
    transform: scale(.5, 1); (adjust as needed)
}
```

Link about transform scale property: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/css-transform

Demo:

**Before:** https://jsfiddle.net/ne7mpufj/1/

**After:** https://jsfiddle.net/ekhm14r0/2/

You'll have to adjust the values in the font-size and transform scale property as needed but that should help get it working for you.

Comment: All you have done is make it smaller ans squooshed the aspect ratio.  He wants the arrow to be the same size and shape, just thinner (less weight)